# How to rank on aggregated sum in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, subquery, window-functions

I want to rank by aggregated points. Example: A guessing game. Day 1: Person A guesses and gets 10 points, person B guesses and gets 9 points. Day 2: Person A gets 5 points, Person B gets 9.

What I want to get is:
On Day 2, Person A has an aggregated amount of 15 points and ranks 2.

Here's the basic table `guesses`:

```
id, person, points, day
1, thomas, 10, 1
2,thomas,5,2
3,marie,9,1
4,marie,9,2
```

I'm having no problems getting the aggregated points grouped by day:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY id) AS total_running_points,
FROM
    guesses
ORDER BY
    day asc;
```

But now I need to rank on every day.

I tried with the following but failed as of course `total_running_points` is a new alias:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY id) AS total_running_points,
    rank() OVER (ORDER BY total_running_points desc)
FROM
    bets_by_day
ORDER BY
    day asc;
```

I sense that I should use a subquery but then I wonder how to partition on it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT b.*, rank() over (order by total_running_points desc) rnk
FROM (
    SELECT b.*, sum(points) over (partition by person order by id) AS total_running_points
    FROM bets_by_day b
) b
ORDER BY day asc;
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned that I can just output a column that I need in the main query with a subquery, perfect!